# ZipFile archives the folders, too

Tags: python

I want to insert all .ini files into an archive; it does it well but when I open my .zip, there are the path folders to those files included, too.

Here's my code:

```
from path import Path
import zipfile

def main():

    folderul_cu_demouri = Path('/my/path/bla/bla')
    nume_arhiva = 'demoz.zip'
    arhiva = zipfile.ZipFile(nume_arhiva, 'w')
    for demo in folderul_cu_demouri.files(pattern='*.ini'):

        arhiva.write(demo)

    arhiva.close()  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

So when I open my zip file, I gotta browse through /my/path/to/files, and only then I can see my .ini files. How can I make it so only the .ini are inserted in the zip file, without the directories?

Thanks.

PS: I'm using path.py to get their extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your files are located directly in the archive folder, you could basename your files and pass the name in `arcname` parameter so the name in the archive is the filename, without the full path:

```
arhiva.write(demo,arcname=os.path.basename(demo))
```

else, you could remove the first characters of the full file path so relative paths are preserved:

```
len_to_strip = len('/my/path/bla/bla')+1

arhiva.write(demo,arcname=demo[:len_to_strip])
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that nori doesn't want to preserve _any_ folder names in the archive, they just want a totally flat structure.

Comment: in that case, the first line answers (it's the easiest one)